# LLVM ICmpInst to Instruction casting

Tags: llvm

I want some piece of advice regarding a LLVM pass. My particular problem is:

There is a method

```
bool patternDC::runOnFunction(Function &F) {
...
    if ( CC->operEquiv(icmpInstrArray[i], icmpInstrArray[j]) ) {...}
...
}
```

having the array elements of type Instruction*.

The called method is

```
bool ifChecker::operEquiv(Instruction *I1, Instruction *I2)
{
...
}
```

BUT I want to use the methods from class ICmpInst inside operEquiv. I cannot do something like

```
ICmpInst** II1 = dyn_cast<ICmpInst*>(I1);
```

(a kind of instanceOf() from Java), having casting compilation problems.

The ICmpInst class is defined at line 913 from http://llvm.org/doxygen/Instructions_8h_source.html 
The inheritance diagram is at http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ICmpInst.html

I want to use the ICmpInst methods for objects of type Instruction. The methods are hard to copy/replicate. What solution I better to use to solve this problem? Should I use visitor pattern (about which I don't know much) ?

Thank you for any suggestion !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to perform the cast is:

```
ICmpInst* II1 = dyn_cast<ICmpInst>(I1);
```

(ditch the extra asterisks)